# Adding Google Firebase in Cocos2dx iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocos2d-x, firebase-analytics

First time using google firebase analytics in iOS SDK.

Now I have downloaded Google Firebase SDK manually...not used Cocoa pods.

Along with analytics it has lots of folders..added all. Am I need to add only analytics related files ?

```
Received linker error : framework not found Protobuf
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Firebase zip instructions:

*5. Drag each framework from the directory named after the SDK into the Project
   Navigator pane.*

From the screenshot, it looks like you're using Firestore, but didn't copy the dependent Protobuf.framework in the Firestore folder:

```
 $ ls ~/Downloads/Firebase/Firestore/
BoringSSL-GRPC.framework    Protobuf.framework      gRPC-C++.framework      leveldb-library.framework
FirebaseFirestore.framework Resources           gRPC-Core.framework
```